# Will java script code ever be exported automatically?

Tags: javascript, gwt, optimization, interop, google-closure-compiler

I've heard it said that GWT will eventually use the closure compiler for code pruning. If they do this the closure compiler wouldn't prune GWT code that's being used by javaScript so javaScript code could call any GWT code as long as the javaScript code is given to the closure compiler? Would this work and if so why do they focus on @JsExport and @JsType? I really excited for Js interop but it seems like the closure compiler offers the potential some effortless interop.